# How to select data where id and date range timestamp in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a problem to make a query for view data in postgresql. I want to view data with 2 condition :

1. where employeeId
2. and between daterange

Heres my Query:

```
Select * 
from employee 
where employeeId = 3 
  and date(created_at) = between '2022-08-29' and '2022-08-31'
```

I have run that query but show error:

Reason:

> SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "date" Position: 1`

The type data of column `created_at` is timestamp.
My questions is: What is correct query for view data from that conditions?

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `=` operator from your query, the `BETWEEN` does not require the `=`

```sql
Select * from employee where employeeId = 3 and date(created_at)  between '2022-08-29' and '2022-08-31'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use arithmetic operation

```
Select * 
from employee 
where employeeId = 3 
  and created_at>='2022-08-29' 
  and created_at< '2022-09-01'
```

Comment: Better use `< 2022-09-01` as the upper limit. Your condition won't include a row created at: `2022-08-31 18:19:20`